# How to open file dialog in screen locker (Antergos / KDE)

Tags: arch-linux, kde, wallpaper, appearance

Relatively new linux user here, I am running Antergos with KDE and am trying use screen locker through the desktop widgets option.

Path: Screen Locker -> Settings -> Desktop Widgets Configure -> Settings -> Slideshow - > Add Folder

I have folders of images that I'd like to use as a slideshow. But when the screen is locked I can't add custom folders due to not being able to view file dialogs(I see a white silhouette of the window instead, for security I assume). I would take a screenshot however I'm not sure how to take a screenshot of the lock screen.

How would I go about adding a custom folder? Is there a way to bypass the security of the lockscreen or is there a config file I can alter?

Comment: I wonder if you could set up the custom folder on a "normal" dashboard, and manually copy the settings over from the config file?